# How remove leading 0 in a string

Tags: dart

I get Ids in a String format that contain leading zeroes. I would like to keep this String format but without the leading zeroes. Example:

```
00 => 0
01 => 1
02 => 2
10 => 10
11 => 11
```

My current implementation is 
String id = int.parse(originalId).toString()

Is there a better / efficient / Dart pattern way to achieve this conversion ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `RegExp` which may be uglier but faster than double conversion :

```dart
"01".replaceAll(new RegExp(r'^0+(?=.)'), '')
```

´^´ matches the begining of the string

`0+` matches one or more `0` character

`(=?.)` matches a group (`()`) of any characters except line breaks (`.`) without including it in the result (`=?`), this ensures that not the entire string will be matched so that we keep at least one zero if there are only zeroes.

Example :

```dart
void main() {

  final List nums = ["00", "01", "02", "10", "11"];
  final RegExp regexp = new RegExp(r'^0+(?=.)');
  for (String s in nums) {
    print("$s => ${s.replaceAll(regexp, '')}");
  }

}
```

Result :

```
00 => 0
01 => 1
02 => 2
10 => 10
11 => 11
```

**EDIT** : Performance test thanks to your comment

```dart
void main() {

  Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  final RegExp reg = RegExp(r'^0+(?=.)');
  for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {
    '05'.replaceAll(reg, '');
  }
  print('RegExp executed in ${stopwatch.elapsed}');

  stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) {
    int.parse('05').toString();
  }
  print('Double conversion executed in ${stopwatch.elapsed}');

}
```

Result :

```
RegExp executed in 0:00:02.912000
Double conversion executed in 0:00:03.216000
```

The more operations you will do the more it will be efficient compared to double conversion. However `RegExp` may be slower in a single computation because creating it has a cost, but we speak about a few microseconds... I would say that unless you have tens of thousands of operations just use the more convenient to you.

Comment: Thanks for your post @Yann39. Are you sure RegExp has better performance? I'm not sure, take a look at this quick and dirty code I've made: https://dartpad.dev/2ff65436310b4a046090422ee098f39d

Comment: Because you are creating a new `RegExp()` each time. Try creating it out of the loop : `var reg = RegExp(r'^[0]*');
  for (int i = 0; i < 999999; i++) { ... //use reg here }`. But a good point that you have created this performance test 

Comment: Thanks @Yann39 for your comment. I updated the code to create the RegExp only once and it changes the results. RegExp seems more efficient!

Comment: Actually the more operations you will do the more it will be efficient compared to double conversion. But for a single operation I think there are no real difference. Unless you have tens of thousands of operations just use the more convenient to you, we speak about nano/microseconds... I have updated my answer to include more details and the performance test.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is trying to prevent leading zeros in a TextField, I made a TextInputFormatter that will remove all leading zeros once a non-zero number is added.

```
class NoLeadingZeros extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
TextEditingValue oldValue,
TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {

if (newValue.text.startsWith('0') && newValue.text.length > 1) {
  return TextEditingValue().copyWith(
    text: newValue.text.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'^0+(?=.)'), ''),
    selection: newValue.selection.copyWith(
      baseOffset: newValue.text.length - 1,
      extentOffset: newValue.text.length - 1,
    ),
  );
} else {
  return newValue;
}
  }
}
```

The tricky part is adjusting the TextSelection offsets once the zeros are removed. Without this update, the TextField will stop working.

Comment: Any particular reason to use `.copyWith`? Why not just creating a new `TextEditingValue` using the default constructor?

Comment: I've tried to come up with a cleaner solution based on your code:
https://gist.github.com/SametSahin10/7cdaa918a68905b28e96cb8747805631

Answer (score 1):

If you have string value such as `"01","001","0230"` and If you want to remove leading zero then try this method. Worked for me.

```
num.parse('001').toInt() // where 001 is a string with leading zero
```

Thanks, Keep Learning

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the most elegant form already! There options for `toStringAsFixed` (https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.19.1/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html, mostly floating points) and `NumberFormat` (https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html), but I feel these might not cover your case

Comment: Thanks @IcarusTyle I think so also. After some tests, trying to measure code performance, the double conversion seems to be the more efficient: https://dartpad.dev/2ff65436310b4a046090422ee098f39d

Comment: As pointed by @Yann39, I corrected my code (see dartpad link above) to avoid creating the RegExp for each number string to convert and the RegExp seems more efficient in term of performance!

Answer (score 0):

I try this function and the result is faster.

```
String removeLeadingZero({required String numberString}) {
  if (numberString.length == 1 && numberString == '0') {
    return numberString;
  }

  String result = '';
  for (int i=0; i < numberString.length; i++) {
    if (numberString[i] != '0') {
      result = numberString.substring(i, numberString.length);
      break;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

code to test:

```
void main() {  
  Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  final RegExp reg = RegExp(r'^0+(?=.)');
  for (int i = 0; i < 200000000; i++) {
    '05'.replaceAll(reg, '');
  }
  print('RegExp executed in ${stopwatch.elapsed}');

  stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  for (int i = 0; i < 200000000; i++) {
    int.parse('05').toString();
  }
  print('Double conversion executed in ${stopwatch.elapsed}');
  
  stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  for (int i = 0; i < 200000000; i++) {
    removeLeadingZero(numberString: '05');
  }
  print('remove leading zero function executed in ${stopwatch.elapsed}');

}
```